# No such property: format for class: java.util.Date

Tags: groovy

The Groovy [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.5.2/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html) says that there should be a `format` method on a `java.util.Date` object. However, when I run my code

```
def nowString = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
```

I get an error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: format for class: java.util.Date
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure this exception is thrown from that line? `MissingPropertyException` like the one you shown would be thrown if you try to access `format` property on the object, something like this: `new Date().format`. The code you have shown calls the method, so it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: May i request you to please dont edit question like this. Your code written above works well after you have remove the bracket(edited the question)

Comment: @Gauravkhurana no it does not. I am still receiving the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

See it works fine. **hope you are not using any extra code**. Tried on Ready API 2.5 java version 1.8

[image]

Also tried on SoapUI V5.4, there also it works fine

[image]

even if i add this statament, results remains the same

```
import java.util.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an additional curly bracket...maybe that is the cause?

You can try to write

```
def nowString = new Date()  
nowString.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
```

Comment: Brace was just a typo. Still nothing :(